# Calculate the number of points with integer coordinates inside the ellipse

Tags: c#, math

Calculate the number of points with integer coordinates inside the ellipse[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhCuW.jpg). Hint: check those values for x and y for which

[image: 1] < 1.

Can

[image: 2] and this be fulfilled? And what about y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point inside the ellipse whose |x| is greater than 13.

If you want to count the number of points with integer coordinates inside the ellipse I would do something like this:

```
int Points = 0;
for(int x = -13; x <= 13; x++)
{
    for(int y = -16; y <= 16; y++)
    {
        if((Math.Pow(x, 2)/169) + (Math.Pow(y, 2)/256) <= 1)
        {
            Points++;
        }
}
```

Clarify the question if you want a more detailed answer because it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you. the task is written this way and even I don't know what needs to be done because I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can query all the points within

```
 x = {-13 .. 13} 
 y = {-16 .. 16}
```

square (follow the hint provided: you should analyze points such that `|x| < 13` and `|y| < 16`). Let's do it with a help of Linq:

```
  int a = 13;
  int b = 16;

  int result = Enumerable
    .Range(-a, a * 2 + 1)
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable
       .Range(-b, 2 * b + 1)
       .Select(y => (x: x, y: y)))
    .Count(p => (double) p.x * p.x / a / a + (double) p.y * p.y / b / b < 1); 

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  647
```

If you want to include points which *on* the ellipse (e.g. `{13, 0}`), just change  `< 1` into  `<= 1`. In this case you'll have `651` points (points `{-13, 0}, {13, 0}, {0, -16}, {0, 16}` are added).